# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxxxxx' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked angular 11

Tags: api, angular11

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxxxxx' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
my code:
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(
'Content-Type',
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'
).set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

return this.http.post(this.rootURL +'/connect/token',
body
,{ 'headers': this.headers })

use it in production

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This issue occurs because you try to access another origin then the one where your app is provided (in your case localhost). This is blocked by the browser for security reasons. There are plenty of answers on stackoverflow, that deal with CORS issues. If its just for development with `ng serve` you could provide a proxy-conf.json to map https://.... to a subpath. like /api.

Comment: I know with ng serve no problem but in production with my real ip to call api appear in google chrome issue I want to know if there is any solution to this problem with code in angular in production

Comment: you cannot get around the CORS blocking from the browser side. Either the Server needs to allow a request from another origin (this is done by adding the access-control-alllow origin header to the response), or the App and the Server need to be deployed under the same domain/IP Address. For both solutions you need to change the server.